# The equivalent proposition about the quotient of two sequences is a sequence of bounded variances

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Given a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ that $x_n\ne 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Define a set

$ A = \{(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx_n $ converge$\},$

prove that for sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, $(\frac{y_n}{x_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded variation sequence $\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ny_n $ converge, $ \forall (a_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in A.$

I have proved that when $(\frac{y_n}{x_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded variation sequence by using Abel test and this lemma:

Lemma: $({a_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is a bounded variation sequence $\iff$ there exist two monotone bounded sequence $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty, (q_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $a_n = p_n + q_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

But I don't know how to prove the opposite side. I have tried to make a counter example to show if
$(\frac{y_n}{x_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ is not a bounded variation sequence, there exist a sequence $({a_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ that $({a_nx_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ converges but $({a_ny_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ not. But I can't find. I would be appreciate it if you have some ideas about this question.

Comment: $\sum a_n <\infty$ and $\sum a_n$ convergent don't mean the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, what I want to say is the sequence is converge, not the sum less than infinity. Thanks for your comment.